# Installing Tensorflow in Windows 10 using Python35

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tensorflow, installation

I want to use Tensorflow(with CPU support only) in Windows 10. I tried the following command to use pip installation but did not work. Any Idea how to fix this?

```
C:/Python35/Scripts/pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Running this in Comman Prompt I get the following error:

```
Collecting tensorflow
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I also tried using pip3 or the URL installation:

```
    C:\>C:/Python35/Scripts/pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled Python35 and used the package from:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow

using the command:

```
pip install "tensorflow-1.1.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"
```

I was able to run the tensorflow on windows properly. You may get several warnings when running a sample Tensorflow code such as:

```
2017-04-19 16:35:22.533979: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2017-04-19 16:35:22.534756: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2017-04-19 16:35:22.535027: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2017-04-19 16:35:22.535245: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2017-04-19 16:35:22.535462: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2017-04-19 16:35:22.535680: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2017-04-19 16:35:22.536664: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. 2017-04-19 16:35:22.536925: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations. b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

To solve this issue you can use the following code to silence the warnings from TF:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
```

Answer (score 1):

anaconda is based on python 3.6 by default and not 3.5xx which supports tensorflow. follow the guide in this link: http://www.stefangordon.com/install-tensorflow-in-anaconda-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue the other day when my `pip` version was out of date.  What version do you have when you type `pip --version` in the console?

I recommend running `pip install --upgrade pip` to update it to the newest version, and then trying again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After several attempts, I just reinstalled my Python35 again and used the new source package 1.1.0 to install and it got solved.

Answer (score 0):

The pip version should be > 9.0
Try upgrade pip:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow's latest library doesn't work with the latest python on win64, you need to downgrade to Python 3.5.x

Tested on win7 Enterprise (64bits, Intel i5):

```
devlab@Ubuntu19 ~/Downloads
$ python --version
Python 3.5.3


devlab@Ubuntu19 ~/Downloads
$ pip install tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\xt21966\downloads\tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-
win_amd64.whl
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.2.0 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
Downloading protobuf-3.3.0.tar.gz (271kB)
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
Downloading Werkzeug-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (312kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
Downloading numpy-1.12.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl (7.7MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in 
c:\users\xt21966\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.1.0)
Installing collected packages: six, protobuf, wheel, werkzeug, numpy, 
tensorflow
Running setup.py install for protobuf: started
Running setup.py install for protobuf: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed numpy-1.12.1 protobuf-3.3.0 six-1.10.0 tensorflow-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.12.2 wheel-0.29.0
```